# How does adbtc.top monitor how long a website you clicked from their ad surf page say open in your browser?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a project similar to http://adbtc.top but I have no idea how they monitor how long you've spent on a website you clicked on from their ads surf page.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction, I know php and javascript. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? This is really a coding help site, so you are encouraged to show your [mcve] and describe what you want to do and what results you get. You might get better results researching over on one of the other SE sites dedicated to web management.

Comment: @jdv I have no idea where to even start from, I've tried googling but I'm not seeing any meaningful results probably because I'm not searching with the right words

Comment: You are in a tricky spot, but the fact is that this is not the right place for this sort of research. Well, you can try and search SE sites and maybe find some hints so you can refine your searches more. But this site is pretty much dedicated to specific questions about code. It really isn't great for general R&D of a concept through to writing some code. You just aren't going to get any traction here.

Comment: @jdv can you please give me a link to other "SE" sites? Thanks

Comment: It's hard to say for sure, but my guess is that measuring time spent on ads is going to be a dark art, and strategies for doing so are going to be a war of escalation with user agents who will be outright  opposed to the idea. But definitely too broad for SO.

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/sites lists them all. But you can literally plop "stack excahnge web" into a search...